# Oracle profiler without 3rd party software

Tags: oracle

I am trying to make something like T-SQL profiler with queries without any 3rd party software.

So first of all I have code for take currently executed queries:

```
select x.sid
,sql_text
from   v$sqlarea sqlarea
,v$session x
where  x.sql_hash_value = sqlarea.hash_value
and    x.sql_address    = sqlarea.address
and    x.username = 'USERNAME';
```

Now I find two challenges:

When I put this code in while loop I am getting error:

```
 DECLARE
  x NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  LOOP
         select x.sid
         ,sql_text
         from   v$sqlarea sqlarea
        ,v$session x
         where  x.sql_hash_value = sqlarea.hash_value
         and    x.sql_address    = sqlarea.address
         and    x.username = 'MAGICAPP';
    EXIT WHEN x > 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 5, column 10: PLS-00428: an INTO clause
>   is expected in this SELECT statement
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Second challenge might be:

- Even if this code above works it would keep refreshing old data with new data by SELECT statement. Would it be possible to append new data to old data with SELECT statement if new data is not found in old data?

**How this should work?**

*Once executed this script should keep running while user not cancel it and than print all queries which it found.*

Comment: Presumably you are aware of all the profiling functionality Oracle already provides?

Comment: @APC Yeah, but this is something that would suit me best if it is possible to work it out,

Comment: This information is already captured in V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY, if you have Enterprise Edition.  If you don't, there are some open source clones, such as Simulated ASH.  If you literally just want to track the statements then it's not a big deal to create your own.  But if you're trying to make a full performance program it's a ginormous task and you probably don't want to reinvent that wheel.

Answer (score 1):

For the error specifically you need an INTO to SELECT the values INTO variables, something like:

```
 DECLARE
  x NUMBER := 0;
  txt VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  LOOP
         select x.sid,sql_text
         INTO   x, txt
         from   v$sqlarea sqlarea
        ,v$session x
         where  x.sql_hash_value = sqlarea.hash_value
         and    x.sql_address    = sqlarea.address
         and    x.username = 'MAGICAPP';
    EXIT WHEN x > 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```